# Как сериализовать классы из JSON с конструкцией any

Tags: java, json, сериализация

Почему не сериализуются классы из объектов в "anyOf"?
Есть например json-схема:

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "anyOf": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/Template"},
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/Limit"}      
      ]
  }
},
  "definitions": {
    "Template": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Limit": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "petName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hunts": {
          "type": boolean
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Сериализуем с помощью библиотеки http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
Получаем:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"foo"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("foo")
private Object foo;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("foo")
public Object getFoo() {
return foo;
}

@JsonProperty("foo")
public void setFoo(Object foo) {
this.foo = foo;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Почему не формируются классы Template, Limit?
Как поступать с такими схемами для сериализации?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас проблема в

```
"hunts": {
      "type": boolean
    }
```

Попробуйте так.

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "anyOf": [
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/Template"},
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/Limit"}      
      ]
     }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Template": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "Limit": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "petName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hunts": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Так можно получить если `foo` конкретного типа

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": 
        {"$ref": "#/definitions/Template"}  
 },
  "definitions": {
    "Template": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "Limit": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "petName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hunts": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за замечание. Это опечатка. Поправил, результат такой же. Вообще это просто пример, я хотел бы понять сам принцип как должны генерироваться классы с конструкцией "anyOf" в json схеме

Comment: @Maxim а что вы ожидаете там увидеть? Два различных шаблона причем никаких родственных связей нет. Будет только Object.

Comment: Ожидалось, что будут ещё классы Template и Limit.

Comment: @Maxim все верно общий знаменатель у них какой?

Comment: Простите я видимо не понимаю. Что имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Maxim тут всё просто еслиб вы указали что список однотипный то у вас был бы там тип. А он у вас может принимать 2 типа. Чтоб это было возможно нужно всзять самую обшую часть, а это Object

Comment: спасибо, а можете подсказать как это объявить в json схеме?

Comment: @Maxim что именно вам нужно указать.

Comment: " тут всё просто еслиб вы указали что список однотипный то у вас был бы там тип. " вот это как указать?

Comment: @Maxim добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Но foo может быть как Template так или Limit. Или совмещение атрибутов из этих двух классов. Как тут быть?:)

Comment: @Maxim Поэкспирементируйте на сайте ничего сложного